# How to import from sibling module in a package, no changes in module files allowed?

Tags: python

Given a folder structure below. **Files a.py and b.py generated and can not be changed.** File b.py imports file a.py. Init file is empty (can be changed). Using my_package getting an error in b.py:

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'*

**How to fix this?**

```
.
└── src
    ├── main.py
    └── my_package
        ├── a.py
        ├── b.py
        └── __init__.py
```

Comment: are you trying to import from . directory?

Comment: a and b are generated by external tool, in b: import a as mega_a

Comment: Your `b.py` file is buggy, and so you should change the tool that generates it. Or put `a.py` at top level (probably in `src`), rather than in your package, since it doesn't belong there.

Comment: @Blckknght files are generated by gRPC, they represent acces interface to a microservice and from my point of view belong to the same package

Comment: Well, maybe your tool has a means of configuring it then? Or you could write some automation scripting to modify the import statements in the files. But `import a` is just wrong if you want `a` to live in a package. You might be able to make it work with some ugly hacking, but it will be messy and not worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__.py` :

```
import sys
sys.path.extend(pkg_directory)
import a
import b
```

`a.py` :

```
def hello():
    print('Hello')
```

`b.py` :

```
import a
```

test:

```
>>> import pkg
>>> pkg.a.hello()
Hello
>>> pkg.b.a.hello()
Hello
```

Comment: looks to me like Derek was just illustrating the import of a from b (which I think is already occurring) - no changes required?  You should try the `__init__.py` changes he suggested, as they look like a good bet to me.

Comment: ya .. was trying to illustrate what is already going on in a and b at a high level..only need to modify __init__ to get the desired behaviour..FYI - his comment was from a previous version, I edited :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer form Derek Eden worked for me. Want to extend it with package init file content I used.

my-package `__init__.py` file:

```
import sys
import os.path

this_pkg_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(this_pkg_path)

import a
import b
```